# How to test the docker containers startup time

Tags: docker, containers, startup

- The 1st way I tried

I used 'time' command to evaluate the docker container startup time in Ubuntu 16.04.

For example:

```
time docker run ubuntu:16.04
```

The return is:

```
real    0m2.601s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.016s
```

I can not figure out which time is the startup time of the container. Could you give me some advices?

- The 2nd way I tried

The containerID I created in 1st way is 267e4f49049c. So, I try to inspect this container.

```
docker inspect 267e4f49049c
```

The returned json include:

```
"StartedAt": "2016-06-15T07:55:02.979652053Z",
"FinishedAt": "2016-06-15T07:55:03.169142266Z"
```

I think the difference of this two time is the container's running time. Am I right?

I don't know if I am in the right way to test the docker container startup time. I will appreciate that If you have some advices.

Comment: All of your info is on the total startup and shutdown/cleanup time. Do you just want the startup, and at what point do you consider it started? When docker launches your app or when the app and initialized and is responding to requests? Docker really doesn't know the latter, so it would be app dependent.

Comment: @BMitch I'm sorry for replying you so late. I found that the "real" time is ok to me.It's  total startup and shutdown/cleanup time.Thank you so much.